# Detecting border pixel of a segmentation label

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I can compute the SLIC boundaries using skimage as follows:

```
def compute_superpixels(frame, num_pixels=100, std=5, iter_max=10,
                        connectivity=False, compactness=10.0):

    return slic(frame, n_segments=num_pixels, sigma=std, max_iter=iter_max,
                enforce_connectivity=connectivity, compactness=compactness)
```

Now, what I would like to do is get the index of pixels which form the boundary of each label. So my idea was to get all pixels belonging to a given segment and then check which pixels have a change in all two directions

```
def boundary_pixels(segments, index):
    # Get all pixels having a given index
    x, y = np.where(segments == index)

    right = x + 1
    # check we are in bounds
    right_mask = right < segments.shape[0]
    down = y + 1
    down_mask = down < segments.shape[1]
    left = x - 1
    left_mask = left >= 0  
    up = y - 1
    up_mask = up >= 0  

    neighbors_1 = np.union1d(right_n, down_n)
    neighbors_2 = np.union1d(left_n, up_n)
    neighbors = np.union1d(neighbors_1, neighbors_2)

    # Not neighbours to ourselves
    neighbors = np.delete(neighbors, np.where(neighbors == i))
```

However, with this all I managed to do was to get the neighbours in the 4 directions of a given label. Can someone suggest some way to actually get all pixels on the border of the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question. The mark_boundaries in the skimage.segmentation package does exactly what I needed.

Usage:

```
processed = mark_boundaries(frame, segments==some_segment)
```

Here frame is he current image frame and segments is the label array. some_segment is the label integer index whose boundaries we are interested in.

Comment: Also have a look at RegionProperties.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the find_contours function available in skimage.measure module to find the co-ordinates of the pixels along the boundary. An example is available at [find_contours.](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_polygon.html/%22Link%22). Next, you can change for change in both directions as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to get this working with the mark_contours function in skimage.segmentation.